# Moving windows on Windows like on Gnome (Alt+DnD)?

Tags: windows, desktop, window-manager

Is there a hidden setting or an external utility that would enable moving windows on Windows like on GNOME?

I'm particularly thinking of moving windows using <kbd>Alt</kbd> + Drag and drop (which can be changed to <kbd>Win</kbd> + drag and drop).

I have machine with Windows (7) and two big monitors at work, and I tend to use multiple smaller windows.  Moving them quickly around is essential, so I'm always missing this GNOME feature.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- [AltDrag](http://code.google.com/p/altdrag/) :

  > AltDrag gives you the ability to move and resize your windows in a new
  >   way. After you have started AltDrag, you can simply hold down the Alt
  >   key and then click and drag any window. Besides just moving windows,
  >   you can resize, maximize and close them too. AltDrag simply allows you
  >   to do more with less mouse movements.
  >
  > This behavior already exists in Linux and other operating systems, and
  >   AltDrag was made with the mission to copy that behavior to the Windows
  >   platform.
- This [AutoHotKey script](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/get-the-linux-altwindow-drag-functionality-in-windows/) can be used as-is, or customised further as per your needs

Comment: A bit laggy compared to resizing by going to the edges, though.

Comment: Great find, I wish I had come to this question first

Answer (score 1):

You can use `win + <Arrow keys>` to snap a window to different edges. Left and right snap the window to take up half the screen, up makes the window full screen, and down restores and minimizes.

You can also arrow left and right repeatedly to hop from one monitor to another.

Is this what you are asking to do?